# MySQL, how to select the row(s) with least sum of two values

Tags: mysql, select

This is my table:

```
mysql> SELECT *  FROM tms;
+----+---------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | tid                 | tse1 | tse2  | bse1  | bse2  |
+----+---------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | -757 | -1052 | -4200 |  -940 |
|  2 | 2017-01-01 01:00:00 | -752 | -1058 | -4175 |  -882 |
|  3 | 2017-01-01 02:00:00 | -754 | -1068 | -4112 |  -906 |
|  4 | 2017-01-01 03:00:00 | -754 | -1057 | -4135 |  -905 |
|  5 | 2017-01-01 04:00:00 | -766 | -1066 | -4140 |  -911 |
|  6 | 2017-01-01 05:00:00 | -767 | -1084 | -4156 |  -916 |
|  7 | 2017-01-01 06:00:00 | -763 | -1092 | -4225 |  -924 |
|  8 | 2017-01-01 07:00:00 | -756 | -1086 | -4322 |  -973 |
|  9 | 2017-01-01 08:00:00 | -779 | -1105 | -4415 |  -989 |
| 10 | 2017-01-01 09:00:00 | -781 | -1114 | -4459 |  -985 |
| 11 | 2017-01-01 10:00:00 | -778 | -1124 | -4579 | -1009 |
| 12 | 2017-01-01 11:00:00 | -783 | -1134 | -4691 | -1010 |
+----+---------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Now I want the row(s) where bse1+bse2 has the lowest value. In my case  ID 3 with value -5018.

I thought this would do it, but no luck ...

```
mysql> SELECT id,MIN(bse1+bse2) FROM tms;
ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'testmaxsum.tms.ID'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Totally new to SQL so please don't be too hard on me.

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design

Comment: If a query of this nature is frequent, maybe add another column with the sum of the two columns.  This should also be able to be done with a "view", `CREATE VIEW viewname AS SELECT` blah blah blah.

Comment: Note: From the demo I ran, it seems that `ID = 3` has the _greatest_ sum of `bse1 + bse2`, not the smallest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM tms 
WHERE bse1+bse2 =
(SELECT MIN(bse1+bse2) FROM tms)
```

Answer (score 2):

To round off the answers already given, I will give an option which would work on MySQL versions 8+.  We can try using the `RANK` analytic function here:

```
SELECT ID
FROM
(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY bse1 + bse2 DESC) rank
    FROM tms
) t
WHERE rank = 1;
```

### Demo

This approach has the added advantage that it would return *all* records which happened to be tied for the greatest value of the `bse1 + bse2` sum.

The demo altered your data set such that two records were tied with the greatest sum.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute the **bse_sum**(`bse1 + bse2`) in the `Select` clause, and [Order](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) the results in ascending order by the **bse_sum** value, and use `LIMIT 1` to get the **lowest** entry (first entry in the ascending order).

Try the following:

```
SELECT id, (bse1 + bse2) as bse_sum 
FROM tms 
ORDER BY bse_sum ASC LIMIT 1
```